# Different byte array for same string in golang and python

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, compression, gzip

I am working on compressing a string using python gzip module and uncompressing the same in golang.

Module to compress string in python:

```
gzip.compress(json.dumps("hello").encode(),-1)
```

Module for decompressing the same in golang:

```
func Decompression(compData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    gr, err := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(compData))
    if err != nil {
        return compData, err
    }
    defer gr.Close()
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(gr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, err
}
```

Getting error : `Gzip:invalid header`

Using the same compression level while compressing and decompressing.

Can anyone please point-out the mistake I am doing?

Comment: Wild guess due to a lack of details in your question: you've used `print` to output the compressed result in Python instead of `write`. `print` make a printable string out of the binary value, i.e `b'\x1f\x8b\x08...`. This of course is not valid gzip.

Comment: Haven't mentioned print in python statement. @Steffen I need to publish the compressed data to kafka, please help in that direction.

Comment: *"I need to publish the compressed data to kafka, please help in that direction."* - This is a completely different question and should be asked as a new one. But maybe have a look at [the Kafka documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression) how compressed input is expected. Or just use [kafka-python](https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/).

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to reproduce, with this code (python3) to generate the file `out.bin`:

```
import gzip
import json

with open('out.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(gzip.compress(json.dumps("hello").encode(), -1))

print(json.dumps("hello"))
```

and this code to read the file and decompress it (which uses your `Decompression` function:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func Decompression(compData []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    gr, err := gzip.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(compData))
    if err != nil {
        return compData, err
    }
    defer gr.Close()
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(gr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, err
}

func main() {
    d, err := ioutil.ReadFile("out.bin")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("raw data: %q\n", string(d))
    data, err := Decompression(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("decompressed: %q\n", string(data))
}
```

The combination works without error. Maybe you didn't save the file correctly from Python somehow? Can you run my go code on your data file and show the raw bytes?